# Container with an image has a strange height

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside the container. The image has a height of `2px` and container has no defined height. For some reason the container takes `18px` of height. If I make an image `18px` high, div takes `22px`, if image is `20px`, div is `24px`. I tried to use display: block, inline and inline-block. Same thing. Then I tried display: flex and it worked. Also, I figured if I just remove the div then I will just have picture with height of `2px`.
So, my question is why the div is taking that height?

```html
<div>
  <img class="colorbar__img" src="https://i.ibb.co/ZgQjMDd/colorstripe.png" alt="Color bar" />
  </div
```

Here is the codepen with an example: https://codepen.io/in43sh/pen/mZMBOp

Comment: are you trying to do a custom border? If so, why not css gradient?

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo It's just a colorbar staying on the top of each page for some reason. It's from the project I'm working on. I haven't thought about using gradient. Isn't the picture too big for it?

Comment: Gradient can be any size at all because it is applied as a background: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients#Creating_color_bands_stripes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried applying `img { display:block }` and that fixed it for me (Chrome, Mac).

The extra height is in there because the browser is rendering the whitespace in the markup as text, applying the font-size and line-height to the content of the div. You might experiment with removing all whitespace from your markup, or setting the font size to zero `.one { font-size:0; line-height:0; }`

Answer (score 3):

It's because, by default, `img` tags are `inline-elements` with a `line-height`. You can get around this by adding css for the img tag to change it to a block element:

```
img {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  display: block;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <img class="colorbar__img" src="https://i.ibb.co/ZgQjMDd/colorstripe.png" alt="Color bar" />
</div>
```